# Microsoft Jet BIT Fields

Tags: ms-access, cdatabase

I am using MFC to manage Microsoft Access databases using`CDatabase`. I support both **mdb** and **accdb** formats.

My understanding of `BIT` fields is:

- `0` or `Null` is `False` or `No`
- `-1` is `True` or `Yes`

Is this always the case? Values of `-1` and `0`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got one little mistake:

- 0 is False/No/Localized equivalent
- -1 is True/Yes/Localized equivalent
- Null cannot exist in a bit field, but will get displayed as an empty field, or an undefined value in a checkbox (filled with either a square or grey dots)

There should never be any other numbers